# I can't install anaconda for python3

Tags: python, macos, python-3.x, anaconda

I want to use Jupyter and all the anaconda packages with Python 3.5.

I already have Anaconda and Jupyter working with Python 2.7, but if I open a Python 3.5 session (I type `python3` in the terminal) it doesn't show the usual anaconda "credits" and I can't import the modules that I want.

So I tried to download the "Anaconda Python 3.5 graphical installer" from the continuum.io website and when I run the installer it says:

> Anaconda is already installed in /Users/user/anaconda. Use 'conda update anaconda' to update Anaconda.

I run it, but it says that all the packages are already installed.

**What I would like:**

I am installing everything from scratch on a new machine (minus the stock Python 2). But on my previous computer, i used to run `python2` or `python3` and have all the packages for both. I also liked that I could type `ipython2 notebook` or `ipython3 notebook` depending on which one i wanted to use. (I know that the command `ipython` is deprecated, what would be the alternative now?)

I've spent some time looking for a solution, somehow I redownloaded the whole anaconda package and created a separate environment for Python 3 and there it worked (i could import `numpy`, etc. after launching `python3`).
But now I have a copy (~1Gb) of anaconda, and I have to use `source activate python3` and `source deactivate` to toggle between the two.

How can I have the same behaviour as I used to do, without having two copies of anaconda_

Comment: Try `source ~/.bashrc`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use your current Anaconda installation and just create an environment based on 3.5. Anaconda will download and install all compatible packages from the repository so you have a complete installation.

In your terminal window / command shell :

```
conda create -n py35 python=3.5 anaconda
```

---

**Mac**:

To use the new environment (in Mac OS X), you can point your IDE to the required environment folder:

```
/Users/username/anaconda/envs/py35/python
```

In the Linux shell, you just need to type:

```
source activate py35
```

---

**Windows**:

To use the new environment (in Windows), you can point your IDE to the required environment folder:

```
C:\Anaconda\envs\py35\python.exe
```

On the Windows command line, you just need to type:

```
activate py35
```

---

**Linux:**

To use the new environment (in Linux), you can point your IDE to the required environment folder:

```
/home/username/anaconda/envs/py35/python
```

In the Linux shell, you just need to type:

```
source activate py35
```

---

Documentation:
http://conda.pydata.org/docs/py2or3.html

You can add as many development environments as you need for Python 2.x/3.x using this method.

Answer (score 0):

The copy of anaconda should be under `~/anaconda`. You might have `anaconda` and `anaconda3`. Remove the one you are not interested in. And in your `~/.profile` you will find lines that initialise your environment. For my install, with command line completion, it look like:

```
# Anaconda
export PATH=~/anaconda/bin:"$PATH"
eval "$(register-python-argcomplete conda)"
```

Make sure you only keep the one you want.